# Laravel Permission Denied Error on CentOs 7

Tags: php, laravel, centos7

I have just installed CentOs 7 with httpd, PHP 7.3 and MariaDB. I configured the virtualhost with the below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName tenancy
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/tenancy/public
</VirtualHost>
```

I got the application displaying the default laravel welcome page but every page that interact with database got `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied (SQL: select * from tenant_modules where (tenant_id = 28))`

While for every api call, I got `file_put_contents(/var/www/vhosts/tenancy/storage/framework/cache/data/44/d1/44d142505dd1a3b497197e2f459d2aec779e9ed6): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

I have set the permission on the www folder to `777 -R` and even done `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t -R \var\www` and still nothing changed. Also, I have written a php function just to test mysql ext and that works.

But when I run `php artisan serve`, it works fine. Do you have an idea of what could be the solution?

Comment: Are you positive your users and groups have permissions to read and write in your Laravel folder? It sounds like the `httpd` (or `www-data`) user doesn't have the correct permissions.

Comment: I added my user to apache group already

Comment: Sure, this means your user can read and write the files. However it looks like your Apache user doesn't have read and write permissions. I will post an answer, hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a permission issue. I suspect your Apache user doesn't have permissions to read and write in your Laravel application folder.

I'm not sure what the Apache user/group is on CentOs. I will assume it's `www-data`, please change as required.

**Disclaimer:** This works on my machine (Debian) but there may be some better ways to set your Laravel app permissions. Feedbacks are welcome.

---

1. Add your user to www-data group:

   `sudo usermod -aG www-data youruser`
2. Change your project user and group ownership:

   `sudo chown -R youruser:www-data /var/www/your-project/`
3. Change your project files permissions to 664:

   `sudo find /var/www/your-project/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;`
4. Change your project directory permissions to 775:

   `sudo find /var/www/your-project/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;`
5. Set ACL permissions to make sure new files created by the webserver have correct permissions:

   ```sh
   sudo setfacl -Rdm g:www-data:rw /var/www/your-project/bootstrap/cache/
   sudo setfacl -Rdm g:www-data:rw /var/www/your-project/storage/logs/
   sudo setfacl -Rdm g:www-data:rw /var/www/your-project/storage/framework/
   sudo setfacl -Rdm g:www-data:rw /var/www/your-project/storage/app/
   ```

Comment: I kept getting `find: missing argument to -exec` while implementing item # 3. The default apache user/group in CentOs is `apache`

Comment: Don't add users to the Apache user group, give Apache the correct permissions to access the content.

Comment: @CrazyMerlin How?

Comment: @LobsterBaz The webserver on most systems already has access to somewhere to log errors, and somewhere to store files temporarily. These are usually /var/log and /tmp. You can create folders for your application in those locations, change the group to whatever the webserver group is (check, don't assume...on CentOS it's httpd, on Ubuntu it's www-data).

The reason for doing things this way is that you can easily add your log files to logrotate, and the garbage collector will purge any files no longer in use. If you want long-term caching, consider OPC, memcached, etc.

Comment: Oh, btw you can check by doing: (wrap from ps to end in backticks...can't do it here)
    echo `ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`

Comment: @CrazyMerlin It makes zero sense to store your application in /var/log or /tmp

Comment: You’re not. Look at how other apps on a Linux box store temporary data. Look at what’s in /var/log...log files

Comment: @CrazyMerlin By design Laravel logs and cache are stored in the project directory. This is how the creator of Laravel intended it, and it's the recommended way to set a Laravel project. It's detailed in Laravel documentation. It makes a lot of sense if you run more than one Laravel project on the same server and you migrate your project from one server to another. Yes, Linux application such as Apache logs belong to `/var/log` and `/tmp` but your Laravel project files belong to your Laravel project directory.

Comment: I don't disagree that's the way that Laravel does it, CakePHP does it the same, as does many other frameworks. What I disagree with is adding the user to the web user group, because that is not the correct way. I offered a solution that works and does not involve security issues. CentOS is a little more strict about such issues, while Debian is not. Deploy the same project to a Debian box and it will most likely just work.